# Easy SQL query for selecting from multiple table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello I have a question concerning following example tables

`Table: Customer -> customer_id, customer_name`

`Table: Product -> product_id, product_serialnumber`

`Table: Customer_Product -> customer_id, product_serialnumber`

Now, how can I get customer_name, while have an input: `product_id`.
I am gonna input `product_id`, and want to select all customer_name who bought this item (`Customer_Product`)

I have got a query but it's soooo:

```
SELECT customer_name 
FROM Customer 
WHERE customer_id IN (
    SELECT customer_id 
    FROM Customer_Product 
    WHERE product_serialnumber IN (
        SELECT product_serialnumber 
        FROM Product 
        WHERE product_id = ?)))
```

Is there any other easy query?

Comment: Post your query here. At least we will see that you tried something.

Comment: (SELECT customer_name FROM Customer WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM Customer_Product WHERE product_serialnumber  IN (SELECT product_serialnumber  FROM Product WHERE product_id = ?)))

thats an horrible query :D

Comment: I edit your question and copy your query there (to help future visitors). And don't forget to accept the answer that you consider that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is fine.  A more typical way to write the query is to use explicit joins:

```
select c.*
from customer c join
     customer_product cp
     on c.customer_id = cp.customer_id join
     product p
     on p.product_serialnumber = cp.product_serialnumber
where p.product_id = @PRODUCT_ID;
```

One downside to this approach is that you might get duplicates, if some customers purchased the product multiple times.  You can, of course, fix this by using `select distinct`:

```
select distinct c.*
from customer c join
     customer_product cp
     on c.customer_id = cp.customer_id join
     product p
     on p.product_serialnumber = cp.product_serialnumber
where p.product_id = @PRODUCT_ID;
```

Comment: here i all columns from Customer - but I only want to get customer_name

Comment: distinct c.customer_name did it^^

Answer (score 2):

**Try this it will work :**

Use **Inner Join**

```
    SELECT t3.`customer_name` FROM Customer_Product t1
    JOIN Product t2 ON t2.`product_serialnumber` = t1.`product_serialnumber` AND t2.`product_id`='$product_id'
JOIN Customer t3 ON t3.`customer_id` = t1.`customer_id`
    JOIN Customer t3 ON t3.`customer_id` = t1.`customer_id`
```

Here, `$product_id` is input by the user.

It is the easiest way to get the data from multiple tables.